# Sitecore PaaS Web DB spikes

Tags: azure, paas, sql-database

We’ve just migrated from Sitecore 8.2.5 on-prem to 9.3 Azure PaaS. Performance seems ok most of the time, but we’re seeing regular spikes to 100% DTU on the web db.

The db is standard S2 50 DTU and we’re running 8 websites. I’m not convinced this adequate but need to convince my company. Is there any optimisations we can do and what tier are others using for their db’s? Thanks.

Comment: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/582735

Comment: The one solution there - increase the DTU from 50 to 100 as a start point

Comment: Is there a rhythm in the spikes? You should try to determine what is happening when those spikes occur.. is anything else spiking as well (cpu, ...)?

Comment: @Madgibbon  We have a similar question answered below please check if that helps

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23126/dtu-shooting-up-after-application-start-in-azure-paas-sitecore-9-0-2/23142#23142

Comment: We identified some of the spikes are coming from client data clean up job. Two of our sites make use of virtual users, this was cause the client data table to grow by 4GB per day. The clean up agent runs every 4 hours for 10 mins. However after 10 mins the job failed due to the amount of data and rolled back. This was causing 20 mins of 100% DTU every four hours.We have now disabled the Sitecore job and setup and Elastic Job to clean the table using a stored procedure at 01:00 every day.

Comment: Defragment the indexes should help. Follow this article https://mikael.com/2019/02/defragment-the-sql-server-heap-on-sitecore-databases/

Comment: You can try implementing the grouping of Azure SQL databases and group into elastic pool. On the basis of usage of dbs you can assign DTUs.

 On the badis of low/high usage you can group the dbs and put them into different elastic pools together.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-overview

Answer (score 0):

Could be load, could be unoptimized queries. I would suggest increasing to S3 to test. If ongoing cost is a concern, you can also try grouping multiple DBs together in an elastic pool to share DTUs.

Comment: Did consider Elastic Pools, but the Sitecore Azure documentation recommends against it.